# Firebase Functions confusion: Which database?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have to be honest I don't understand at all how to specify which database I'm talking to. Is FireStore to be considered one ginourmous database, with the documents and collections of all my applications living side by side?

Do I have to give app specific names for the collections... say AwesomeAppUsers, and ThatOtherAppUsers, and AnotherAppUsers? Or what? Just mutually mash together users under "/users"?

I'm reading through the Firebase documentation, and all I'm seeing are lines of code referring to a particular collection, or document, but none that refers to any namespaces, or databases.

There's no setup, no config for where it should be pointed, you just sign in with firebase, and then you run

`firebase deploy --only functions`

And then magic.

Can someone please demagicify this, and explain me how an app can communicate with specific functions, when there's no setup?

The worst is when I see this in app writing guides. Like here http://resocoder.com/2018/05/25/firebase-firestore-chat-app-cloud-functions-fcm-ep-8-kotlin-android-tutorial/, two different repositories, a backend and an app... how does the app know which of the quintillion backend functions you'll be writing to subscribe to?

```
 return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload).then( response => {
            const stillRegisteredTokens = registrationTokens

            response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
```

How does .sendToDevice not send to all devices in the universe, but only those specifically the app... which again is set up in a different repository... no configs, nothing pointing to that. Where does that take place?

How does this function "know" only to send messages to those specific Android apps associated wit this?

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = req.query.text;
    // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    return admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then((snapshot) => {
        // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
        return res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
    });
});

// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const original = snapshot.val();
    console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
    const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
    // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
    // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
    // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
    return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you create a project in firebase you need to download a file called **google-services.json**. This file looks like [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mock-google-services.json).

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_id": "mockproject-1234",
    "project_number": "123456789000",
    "name": "FirebaseQuickstarts",
    "firebase_url": "https://mockproject-1234.firebaseio.com"
  },
```

and a lot more. It specifies the project you're working on. If you working on a backend using firebase, the same applies, there's a special configuration file you need to use and this tells your local project which firebase project it will be working on.

Each firebase project has their own database, cloud firestore or realtime, so you can only alter one database at the time, the one associated with that little file/project.

The same for notifications and everything else included in firebase. All of them are restricted to your project which is specified by the **google-services.json** file.

When you upload a cloud functions you uploaded it to a specific project, which will make them work with the devices of that project, usually the devices of that project have the google-services.json file associated with such project.

Comment: Ah yes, and in the project you make by running `firebase init function` there is a `.firebaserc` file which specifies the project you attach it to. Thank you.

It was confusing to me because the firebase tool was signed in to a different, but similar user to the one I had created the project for Firebase Console. Things make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

> How does .sendToDevice not send to all devices in the universe, but only those specifically the app... which again is set up in a different repository... no configs, nothing pointing to that. Where does that take place?

Every Firebase client SDK gives you the ability to create a registration token on the device like an app on the smartphone for example. After you've created that token on the device, you need to save it in a document at your Firestore or in your Realtime Database.

**Device registration token on Android**:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

Now you can use this token to send messages over Firebase Cloud Messaging within your Firebase Function.

**Sending to individual devices documentation at Firebase:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices